# href not working in greasemokey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have following code in my greasemonkey script. In case, i am unable to save my order to server, i display an error message and then a link (created using `<a href>` to save it again. this link is `save_order` method again. But this is not working. I tried debugging into it but no luck. (I have basic understanding of JavaScript)

```
function save_order() {
    server_url = 'https://server.com/api/put_order?user_id=' + form.user.value +'&order_id=' + orderId;
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url: server_url,
        onload: function(response){
            if(response.status == 200){
                localstorage.removeItem(orderId);
                messageBar.innerHTML += '<br/>Order has been saved successfully.';
            } else {
                if (errorBar.style.display === 'none'){
                    errorBar.style.display = 'block';
                }
                errorBar.innerHTML += '<br/>Error saving. <a href="#" onclick="save_order();return false"><b>Try Again</b></a>';
            }
        }
    });
}
```

=======

**FULL CODE**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         SaveOrder
// @version      1.0
// @author       myname
// @include      https://xx*.xxxxxxxx.com*/*
// @run-at       document-end
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

var saveButton = document.getElementById('save-button');
saveButton.addEventListener("click", save_order,true);
var info_bar = document.getElementById('info_bar');
var error_bar = document.getElementById('error_bar');
var form = document.getElementById('place_order_form');
var order_id = form.order_id.value;

var localstorage = window.localStorage;

if (localstorage.getItem(order_id)){
    save_to_db();
} 

function save_order(){
    localstorage.setItem(order_id, order_id);
}

function save_to_db() {
    var random_boolean = false;//Math.random() >= 0.5;

    console.log(random_boolean);

    server_url = 'https://xxx.xxxx.com/api/put_order?user_id=' + form.user.value +'&order_id=' + order_id;
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url: server_url,
        onload: function(response){
            if(response.status == 200 && random_boolean){
                localstorage.removeItem(order_id);
                info_bar.innerHTML += '<br/>Order saved successfully';
            } else {
                if (error_bar.style.display === 'none'){
                    error_bar.style.display = 'block';
                }
                error_bar.innerHTML += '<br/>Error saving. <a href="#" onclick="save_to_db();"><b>Try Again</b></a>';
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method works just fine, as you can see in this example.

You probably have an error elsewhere.

```js
function test(){
  document.body.innerHTML += '<a class="function-link" href="#" onclick="test();">Test</a>';
}
```

```html
<a class="function-link" href="#" onclick="test();">Test</a>
```

**EDIT :** I did some digging, and found a way around your issue.

Instead of adding an `onclick` on your link, create an event handler in javascript attached to a `save-to-db` class like this :

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.closest('a') && e.target.closest('a').classList.contains("save-to-db")) {
        save_to_db();
    }
});
```

Now all you need to do is get rid of your `onclick` and replace it with `class="save-to-db"`

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<br/>Error saving. <a href="#" class="save-to-db"><b>Try Again</b></a>';
```

It works like a charm now :

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.closest('a') && e.target.closest('a').classList.contains("save-to-db")) {
        save_to_db();
    }
});

save_to_db();

function save_to_db() {
    console.log('Function called');
    document.body.innerHTML += '<br/>Error saving. <a href="#" class="save-to-db"><b>Try Again</b></a>';
}
```

Comment: how can i debug that error? Also, what does `return false` means in my code next to `save_order();`?

Comment: looking at chrome console, it says that `save_order` isn't defined. Is it because i am calling same method which is creating the div?

Comment: If `save_order` isn't defined, it means you are overwriting it elsewhere.

Comment: @EmAe Or that you declared `save_order` inside a block that can't be reached.

Comment: @EmAe I forgot to tell you I edited my answer with a working solution :)